# Tornado Scheduler

Tags: python, asynchronous, tornado

What is the best way (pattern) to create scheduler with Periodic Callback in tornado: execute scheduled job in specific datetime

Answer (score 6):

You should use a **PeriodicCallback**

**class tornado.ioloop.PeriodicCallback(callback, callback_time, io_loop=None)**

*Schedules the given callback to be called periodically.
The callback is called every callback_time milliseconds.*

From: [Tornado Callbacks](http://tornado.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ioloop.html#callbacks-and-timeouts)

Answer (score 3):

This links may be useful:

- [Tornado IO Loop - add_timeout](http://www.tornadoweb.org/documentation/ioloop.html#tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.add_timeout)
- [Understanding the code inside tornado](http://golubenco.org/2009/09/19/understanding-the-code-inside-tornado-the-asynchronous-web-server-powering-friendfeed/) (have a look at the Timers paragraph)

Basically you can use the *`add_timeout`* method of the current *`ioloop`* instance like this:

```
# Schedule callback to be executed 5 seconds from now
ioloop.IOLoop.instance().add_timeout(time.time() + 5, callback)
```

Hope it helps.